# Windshield washer fluid reservoir leaking at pump plug. Quick Fix?

Tags: windshield-washer

I filled the reservoir and noticed a drip. I took it out, emptied it, and found the source of the leak. The plug that goes in at the bottom of the reservoir was leaking (see picture). Besides buying a new plug and/or reservoir, anyone have a quick fix to get a better seal on the plug?

It's a 1998 Chevrolet Metro/Toyota Corolla.

The car is a total beater that I bought 2 years ago for $300 bucks. I've been learning a lot by doing minor cost effective repairs.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drain it, dry it, and apply liberal amounts of silicone sealant?